# Custom Style format color not shown in the format selector

Tags: php, css, wordpress, tinymce

When selecting the format, the word in the editor's color is changed. Functionality is working fine. All the selector are shown and also applied on selected.

But  the color of the selector also need to be different according to the color it is going to set. It is shown in tinymce example. http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php here the selectors are red.

Code i have used is:

```
$color = array(
        'title' => "Light Grey",
        'inline' => 'span',
      'styles' => array('color'=>'#232323'),
      'wrapper' => false,
        );
```

It is just showing all black in selector. But it is working fine in the texts in editor. The color are changed after selecting the format.

[image]

Wrapping code is as follows:

```
    function atg_mce_buttons_2( $buttons ) 
  {
    array_unshift( $buttons, 'styleselect' );
    array_unshift( $buttons, 'fontsizeselect' );
    return $buttons;
  }

  function atg_mce_before_init( $settings ) 
  {


    $style_formats = array(

      array(
        'title' => 'Content Heading',
        'block' => 'h2',
        'classes' => 'h2'
        ),
      array(
        'title' => 'Content Sub Heading',
        'block' => 'h5',
        'classes' => 'h5'
        ),
      array(
        'title' => 'Paragraph',
        'block' => 'p'
        ),
      array(
            'title' => 'Red Uppercase Text',
            'inline' => 'span',
            'styles' => array(
                'color'         => 'red', // or hex value #ff0000
                'fontWeight'    => 'bold',
                'textTransform' => 'uppercase'
            )
        )

      );
    $settings['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );

        return $settings;
      }
    add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init',  array(&$this,'atg_mce_before_init' ));
    add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2',  array(&$this,'atg_mce_buttons_2' ));
```

Comment: [See if this post helps](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128931/tinymce-adding-css-to-format-dropdown/128950#128950)

Comment: My code seems to be fine. It is also working fine as I have mentioned. The selected text in editor is changing the color. Just that the selectors are black instead of their respective colors.

Comment: could you show wrapping code?

Comment: I have added the wrapping code. I have also tried with the code in examples. The "red upper text" from example is also not shown red, however works in the text selected.